# Necessity to serve a single page application through HTTPS

Tags: ajax, security, ssl, https, single-page-application

I'm currently working on a single page application that talks to a REST api hosted on a different server and protected with SSL.

I am wondering if I should set an SSL certificate on the server that serves the single page application or if simply setting it on the back end server is enough, by considering the following:

1. The single page application is an endpoint for reset password links with a confidential token in the query string. These links are sent by email to my users. When a user clicks on the link, his browser requests the single page application. The GET request is therefore NOT encrypted and nor is the query string.
2. The app then asks the user to enter a new password and this new password is sent via ajax to the back end, which is protected with SSL.

So my take on it is that it's worth setting up SSL for my single page application to assure security for the first consideration because the GET request is therefore NOT encrypted and nor is the query string and the token is sensitive information. However, it wouldn't be required if only the second consideration was taken into account since the connection between the single page app and the back end is done via SSL (because the single page app uses Ajax to communicate to an endpoint protected via SSL).

Am I right? Or completely sidetracked? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your intuition is correct. The only effective difference between your first and second scenario is that in (1) you are sending sensitive information (the token) to the front end server, and (2) you are sending sensitive information (password) to the back end server. So because you are sending sensitive information to both, they will both need to be secured by SSL.

---

If the front end server were not secured by SSL, here is a possible attack avenue:

1. Attacker MITMs the frontend server when the user sends the reset token in the query string, the attacker gains access to the reset token.
2. Before the real client can send a password reset request, the attacker sends the password reset request to the backend server.
3. The attacker sends the new password to the backend server. The password is reset to a password the attacker knows.

In no step does the attacker have to compromise the SSL of the backend server to pull off this attack on the frontend server. Of course the backend server will be receiving the password from the user, so it will need SSL too. In short, to protect against man-in-the-middle attacks you will need SSL for both of your servers.